# Getting network details from Active Directory in VB script?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, active-directory, windows-authentication

There are needs when we want to populate user details from Active Directory. Sharing my code to access user details from AD.

Comment: [Related](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/adquery.shtml).

Comment: This is likely to collect some downvotes - self-answer questions are held to the same standard as others including research, effort, clarity on the problem etc

Answer (score 0):

Introduction

People often ask for querying active directory by passing network account name or email. There are many articles already available on this, and one might get confused. Here is simple working code to access user detail from active directory database-
Please note in order to access AD, you have to specify valid network account credentials in connection.

```
function GetADDetails(userId)
  Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  objConn.provider ="ADsDSOObject"
  objConn.Properties("User ID") = "domain\userId" 'specify domain and 
  network account
  objConn.Properties("Password") = "password" 'specify network password
  objConn.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True
  objConn.open "Active Directory Provider"
  Set objCom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  Set objCom.ActiveConnection = objConn
  strTarget="GC://abc.com" 'your domain name
  objCom.CommandText ="select sn, givenName, sAMAccountName, name,mail,      
  telephoneNumber FROM '"+strTarget+"' where sAMAccountname='"+userId+"'"
  Set objRS = objCom.Execute
  If Not (objRS.EOF Or objRS.BOF) Then
    GetADDetails=objRS.GetRows
  Else
    GetUserData = Null
  End If
  'Close objects and remove from memory
  objRS.Close
  objConn.Close
  Set objRS = Nothing
  Set objConn = Nothing
  Set objCom = Nothing
end function
```